# How to group items by path (graph structure) and leave only those with highest score using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with records and their scores (table 'Offers'):

```
OfferId     OfferScore
----------- -----------
1           1
2           20
3           3
4           4
5           5
6           6
7           7
8           8
```

These records might be related. All relations are stored in the table 'OffersRelation':

```
OfferId1    OfferId2
----------- -----------
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
2           3
3           5
7           8
```

I want to remove all related Ids (within the group) from table Offers and leave only ones with the highest score.

In my case :

Offers with Ids: 1,2,3,4,5 are related ("group") and the offer with id:2 has the highest score:20 so I want to remove ids: 1,3,4,5 and leave only the one with id:2 from this "group".

Offer with Id:6  doesn't have any related items (no relations in the table OffersRelations) so it stays in the table Offers.

Offers with Ids:7,8 are related and Offer with id:8 has higher score than 7 so i want to remove the offer with id:7 and leave the offer with id:8 from this "group".

Expected result in the table Offers:

```
OfferId     OfferScore
----------- -----------
2           20
6           6
8           8
```

### How to do it in t-sql?

Data from examples:

```
drop table if exists dbo.Offers
drop table if exists dbo.OffersRelation
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Offers](
    [OfferId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfferScore] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OffersRelation](
    [OfferId1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OfferId2] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Offers]
           ([OfferId],[OfferScore])
     VALUES (1,1),(2,20),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[OffersRelation]
           ([OfferId1]
           ,[OfferId2])
     VALUES
            (1,2),
            (1,3),
            (1,4),
            (1,5),
            (2,3),
            (3,5),
            (7,8)
```

Comment: `select top 1 * from tablename order by score1 desc`

Comment: what do you mean by a,b,c,d there?  It isn't very clear since the letters don't reappear anywhere

Comment: The first part of your question is out of step with the second part.  I'm not seeing the edge case of duplication in your sample data.

Comment: You aren't asking about duplicates at all. You are looking for *cycles*.

Comment: give me 2 min, I will update and explain

Comment: How many steps can there be from one ID to another? If there are only up to eg 3 steps you could join the table to itself 3 times and check whether `ID2` from the last table points back to `ID1` of the first one

Comment: there is only 1 unique record with unique relation 'a' (Id1=1711) and 'b' (Id2=2594704) but there might be unlimited connections to other records: 'a' (Id1=1711) and 'xyz' (Id2=1234545677890)

Comment: @free4ride your edit didn't explain anything. Those are *not* duplicates. Don't use that word, it means something completely different. And no, the examples don't show any sameness. There's no `a` that points to the same `b` as anything else, there are three rows whose `ID2` values are different.

Comment: @free4ride all 7 records are unique. There's nothing "same" in your examples. The only relation I could think is that `17611-2594704-190988979` has the same start and end as `1711-2597306-190988979`

Comment: Well, It's still not clear what it is that you're asking. Please note that sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: `select 
 top 1 with ties 
 t.Id1 
 from  TableName t
 order by row_number() over (partition by t.Id1 order by t.Id2 desc)`

Comment: Well now it's a bit more clear but I will not vote to reopen a question like this. The least you should do is post DDL+DML for your sample data instead of images.

Comment: I updated the question with all you asked for - I hope it's clear now

Comment: Already voted to reopen yesterday. You need 3 move votes. Hope you get them.